# Three divs inline with middle fixed-width horizontally centered

Tags: html, css, web

I am designing responsive website, with content being 320px to max 960 px width horizontally centered div. Now I want to do header strip, which is an image as long as screen width, to be not affected in content box, but want the rest, which is outside this 960px strip to be blacked out. This image will explain it better:

[image: http://i.minus.com/ibtSnl17wZsRHN.jpg]

I tried at first to do linear gradient, but I don't know exact position of breakpoints. I tried black, semitransparent divs, but couldn't manage to do them properly.

Is there any way to do this with pure css3 or I must use js/jquery? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Comment: So you just want the center area (where the content will be) to not have the transparent black layer over the header image? Or do the three divs play any specific part in this?

Comment: Actually, my goal is to have part of image in content not touch, and the rest of it faded-out. So it's closer to "not have the transparent black layer over the header image".